# How to copy and paste files from one windows to another?

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2

host A : Windows 10

host B : RDP Windows Server 2012

I want to copy and paste a file or folder from Windows 10 to Windows Server.

Used to be able to do it in my previous work.

Comment: AFAIK you can't do that. You can copy and paste though.

Comment: And you can make local drives available on the remote computer (if the domain admin has allowed you to do so).

Answer (score 0):

[Mouse without borders](https://www.microsoft.com/en-gb/download/details.aspx?id=35460). This basically is a tool that tethers two or more computers together and allows the mouse and files to be moved between two machines. It's as reliable as the connection the computers have with eachother (LAN).

Comment: This is designed for using computers which are physically present next to each other and on the same physical network link. How is it useful in the OP's scenario?

Comment: VPN and it will still work where you can drag it to the other host. Not ideal I completely understand but it's clever software that is better than no answer...

Comment: Thanks for the input. Before i was going what Gerald  mentioned copy from local to rdp. Now i cant do it, so i believe some kind of service should be running. I am not sure how you transfer files becuse its not ftp or scp used.